# Can I visit Norway on my Passport Talent (France) visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, france, norway

My visa says:

> Valid for: France
> From: 11-12-22
> Until: 10-04-23
> Duration of stay: XXX
> Type of visa: D
> Number of entries: Mult
> Remarks: Pass. Talent; Chercheur; PT4 VLSTS; Valider en ligne

Can I enter into Norway on this visa?

Answer (score 4):

You definitely can, a national D visa gives you access to other Schengen members for short-stays, this provided you don't get over the 90/180 clock